# Define method code using fluent interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class Rule:

```
public class Rule {

  public abstract Boolean Check(Decimal value);

  private Boolean Cross(Decimal value1, Decimal value2) {
    // Cross code
  } 

  private Boolean Validate(Decimal value) {
    // Valdate code
  } 

}
```

Then I create my rules:

```
public class MyRule: Rule {

  public override Boolean Check(Decimal value) {
    // Code using value and Cross and Validate base methods
  }

}
```

I would like to also define the code in Check method using Fluent interface:

```
Model.Rule(x => {
  // Define check code using value, Cross and Validate methods
})
```

Then in Model class I would need to get the result of the check code.

Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you give some code examples on how you plan to use your `Rule` class?

Comment: The way you create a fluent interface is to make each instance method for the type be declared to return a reference to an instance of that type. In the implementation of the methods, each method should `this`

Answer (score 0):

Define `Rule` as an extension method on the type `Model`, that take `this Model model` and `Func<Decimal, Bool> checkFunc` as parameters.

In this extension method create an instance of `RuleFromLambda` where the class `RuleFromLambda` implements `Rule` and take `Func<Decimal, Bool> checkFunc` as constructor parameter. The implementation of `Check` in  `RuleFromLambda` is just a call to `_checkFunc`.

Then, in the `Rule` extension method, attach the instance of `RuleFromLambda` to `model` in whatever is the way you want to (original question doesn't show how rule and model are connected).
Then return the model (or the `RuledModel`) to allow subsequent fluent calls.